# How to efficiently sample y in intervals of Δx in an “ascending” cubic Bézier curve?

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, bezier

For a cubic Bézier curve defined by control points P0, P1, P2 and P3 with the formula

```
B(t)=(1−t)^3*P0 + 3(1−t)^2t*P1 + 3(1−t)t^2*P2 + t^3*P3
```

we can get a point corresponding to any t ∈ [0,1]. However, from what I've gathered, algebraically solving for either one of the coordinates becomes very tedious and costly, at least for a general solution.

Now, suppose we have a two-dimensional curve B(t)=(x,y) with the specific constraint that dx/dt > 0 for all 0 ≤ t ≤ 1, i.e. the curve can progress to the positive x direction, but never "straight up/down" or "backwards", is there an efficient algorithm (/algebraic manipulation trick) to sort of "sample" the y of the curve with respect to a constant interval Δx that can leverage this property?

Comment: Could scaling and translating the curve so that the first anchor point lies on the origin (0,0) and the last one is at (1, y) help simplify the problem, since then both x and t run through [0; 1]?

Comment: Why is solving the equation "tedious"? After all, there is an analytic solution for cubic polynomials.

Comment: @EHOOPZ can you explain what you're trying to do that makes you think you need a) these contraints and b) these constraints specifically applied to a *Bezier curve* rather than a non-parametric function, which would make all those constraints much easier to work with. It feels like you're asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), so see if you are and if so, please update your question so it addresses your real problem first (or even "only").

Comment: Your parametrization would be `(t,y( x^-1(t) ))` so it's still the same "tedious" solving... Just use [the formulas](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/)

Comment: I've been experimenting with non-parametric functions, which might indeed be a better fit for what I'm trying to do - I wasn't aware that constructing a cubic polynomial that goes through a set of specified points was so simple. Thank you all, I'll report my findings later. :)

Comment: Well I personally find [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++x+%3D+(1-t)%5E3*a+%2B+(1-t)%5E2*t+*+b+%2B+(1-t)t%5E2+*+c+%2B+t%5E3+*+d+for+t)  quite tedious. But it's doable :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer what I think you're asking, rather than what you're actually asking, so if this doesn't cover it (and even if it does) you will want to update your post to clarify what you really mean.

> Now, suppose we have a two-dimensional curve B(t)=(x,y) with the specific constraint that dx/dt > 0 for all 0 ≤ t ≤ 1, i.e. the curve can progress to the positive x direction, but never "straight up/down" or "backwards", is there an efficient algorithm (/algebraic manipulation trick) to sort of "sample" the y of the curve with respect to a constant interval Δx that can leverage this property?

Bezier curves are affine transform invariant, so any curve that does fit this definition can be rotated to no longer fit that definition. Let's assume you are referring to some canonical form, where you preprocess the curve by applying a rotation/translate to it such that the first point is at (0,0), and the last point is some coordinate (>0,R) (that is, x coordinate greater than 0, and y coordinate "any real number").

Given that, your constraints mean that the first control point (which determines the tangent at the curve at `t=0`) must lie strictly to the right of (0,0). The `y` coordinate is irrelevant (it just needs to be a real number), and the `x` coordinate can be any real number greater than 0 (even something as close to zero as IEEE floating point numbers allow).

Conversely, the end coordinate needs to be similarly approached, so for any end coordinate (ex,ey), the associated control point (which determines the curve tangent at `t=1`) needs to lie strictly to the left of (ex,ey); that is, the `y` coordinate can be anything, and the `x` coordinate must be to less than `ex`, but again it can be as close as possible without *being* `ex`.

Done, we now have a curve that fits your needs, which leaves the sampling at fixed `x` interval: you have three options.

1. The mathematically true way to do this is to reparameterise your curve such that `y` becomes and expression of `x` and that is ludicrously hard.
2. You know the tangent at each point, and Cubic Bezier curves that conform to your needs do not oscillat, so you can compute a guess for "the next `x`" and then use the Newtonian approach to find the true next `x` value you need. Or,
3. solve this the programming way: you're going to be drawing this curve anyway, so during the draw routine, build the LUT for the curve points that need to be drawn to the screen: you now have a list of `x` values with associated `y` values and you just need to do a simple lookup.

Obviously, unless you need absolute scientific precision, option 3 is going to be by far the best choice.